# maven: filtered resource not being packaged in WAR file

Tags: maven, resources, filter, war, pom.xml

I have a maven project in which I'm using the maven-war-plugin to package the project:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

I have set a filter from a property file based on which ever environment I'm building for:

```
<filters>
    <filter>properties/${env}.properties</filter>
</filters>
```

I'm attempting to filter an xml file located in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I build the project from the command line using:

```
basedir> mvn clean package -Denv=dev
```

Which creates the following in my target directory:

```
--- target
    +-- classes
    +-- project-name
    --- project-name.war
```

The xml files in target/classes ARE properly filtered. However, the xml files in project-name.war/WEB-INF/classes ARE NOT filtered.

How can I fix my pom file or project directory structure to have filtered resources included in the packaged war file?

Comment: Did you really mean `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`?  You have a **classes** directory under your **source** tree?  I am not sure that the WAR plugin will pick that up.  If that doesn't pan out to be the problem you can try excluding the leading `${basedir}`.  I am using `<directory>src/main/resources</directory>` with success.

Answer (score 7):

Webapp resource filtering is treated differently. This is done through [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <filters>
        <filter>properties/${env}.properties</filter>
      </filters>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <!-- set files to include, defaulted to ** -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/pattern1</include>
          </includes>
          <!-- set files to exclude  -->
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/pattern2</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```